# What is the longest sequence of increasing White moves with only White pieces?

Tags: problems, records, mathematics

Inspired by a comment by @Evargalo on [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/longest-sequence-of-moves-where-number-of-available-moves-increases), I ponder how long a sequence can last where each turn, White has more available moves than the previous turn, in a situation with only White pieces present on the board. With no Black pieces to add moves via potential captures with, it is interesting to wonder how the geometry of the pieces' powers can be manipulated.

Comment: Hang on, after 2.c4, White has the same number of moves as before: one more queen move and one less move with wPc. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Laska You are correct; removed.